# Pandas Combining City and State Strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a `locations` column containing a string of city and states. I would like to join the city with the state.

```
0       Seattle, WA,Portland, OR,Everett, WA,Oklahoma ...
1       Silver Spring, MD,Portland, OR,Everett, WA,Den...
2       Oklahoma City, OK,Kingston, WA,Gardner, MA,Tul...
3       Portland, OR,Oklahoma City, OK,Eugene, OR,Corv...
4       Silver Spring, MD,Seattle, WA,Everett, WA,Spok...
3241    Seattle, WA,Silver Spring, MD,Portland, OR,Okl...
```

From research on SO, I came across the recommendation to split and join them back together. However, I could not get the `join`/`zip` to work.

`test_df['locations'].str.split(',')`

Here is what I was trying through assignment:

`' '.join, zip(test_df['locations'][0::2], test_df['locations'][1::2])`

Desired output:

```
0       ['Seattle, WA','Portland, OR', 'Everett, WA', 'Oklahoma City, OK']
1       ['Silver Spring, MD', 'Portland, OR', 'Everett, WA', 'Denver, CO']
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Setup:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'locations': {0: 'Seattle, WA,Portland, OR,Everett, WA',
  1: 'Silver Spring, MD,Portland, OR,Everett, WA',
  2: 'Oklahoma City, OK,Kingston, WA,Gardner, MA',
  3: 'Portland, OR,Oklahoma City, OK,Eugene, OR',
  4: 'Silver Spring, MD,Seattle, WA,Everett, WA',
  3241: 'Seattle, WA,Silver Spring, MD,Portland, OR'}})
```

**Solution:**

If location has fixed pattern of having n pairs of 'city, state', it can be done as below:

```
import numpy as np
(
    df.locations.str.split(',')
    .dropna()
    .apply(lambda x: x+[''] if len(x)%2 != 0 else x)
    .apply(lambda x: [','.join(e) for e in np.asarray(x).reshape(-1,2)])
    .tolist()
)

[['Seattle, WA', 'Portland, OR', 'Everett, WA'],
 ['Silver Spring, MD', 'Portland, OR', 'Everett, WA'],
 ['Oklahoma City, OK', 'Kingston, WA', 'Gardner, MA'],
 ['Portland, OR', 'Oklahoma City, OK', 'Eugene, OR'],
 ['Silver Spring, MD', 'Seattle, WA', 'Everett, WA'],
 ['Seattle, WA', 'Silver Spring, MD', 'Portland, OR']]
```

Comment: this is not the expected output

Comment: It's a display issue. I've changed it to list which looks better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (2)` with this though. I am assuming that relates to the n pairs in your solution?

Comment: It's most likely there are some paris which don't have city or state. I've updated the answer to handle that.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks for your help!